How do I store logical expressions in a database?
I need to store boolean expressions in a database, example:
(VAR1 > 20 AND VAR2 < 30) OR (VAR3 != 10 AND VAR 4 == 5).

That is, it is any combination of comparison operations, logical operations and parentheses. I tried to design a lot of entities and a lot of relationships for this, but I couldn't take into account all the options and it turned out to be "Not very good" to put it mildly.
Can you please help me with this? Maybe I can store them as a text field, which is a json? I just don't understand how entities can be linked so that my task is solved.
I say right away, I don't need to do them right away or something else, I need to store them, and then receive them, and then perform them depending on other conditions.
Here's what I was able to design (entities and connections):
Rule(ID)
ComparisonOperation(ID,RuleID, ComparisonValue, Operation(>, <, ==...))
LogicalOperation (ID, Operation (AND, OR), ComparisonoperationID, Logicaloperation1ID, Logicaloperation2ID).

This allows you to store a chain of expressions without parentheses: VAR1 > 2 OR VAR2 < 1 AND... . But if the brackets appear, then nothing will work. Pay attention to the connection itself in entity "Logical operation", I'm not sure if this is correct. In general, it looks terrible, but I need to do it. Please help me, suggest options for how to do this?

First convert your expression to the disjunctive normal form. At that point you don't need the parentheses any more: the AND operator now always has precedence over the OR operator.
Then we could have:
Rule(RuleID)
Comparison(ComparisonID, ConjunctionID, RuleID, ComparisonValue, Operation(>, <, ==...))
Conjunction(ConjunctionID, DisjunctionID)
Disjunction(DisjunctionID)

The expression would be represented by one Disjunction.

That Disjunction consists of 1 or more Conjunction, and
Each Conjunction consists of 1 or more Comparison, and
Each Comparison is about a Rule


What if you wanted to also allow (x == 5 or y > 4) and z < 200?

@Zohar, as I wrote at the start, you would first convert it to the equivalent expression in disjunctive normal form.
